# How to ignore specific foreign key in sequelize while joining tables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have been pulling my hairs last couple of hours to figure this out. I am using `sequelize` orm for an `express` app. The `sequelize` doc is super confusing for me and I have been trying to find solutions but ended up with none so far.

I have three associations

```
//models/device.js


device.associate = function(models) {
        device.hasMany(models.actuator_activity, {
          foreignKey: 'actuator_device_id',
          as: 'actuator_activities',
        });
        device.hasMany(models.actuator_activity, {
          foreignKey: 'sensor_device_id',
        });
        device.hasMany(models.sensor_data, {
          foreignKey: 'sensor_device_id',
          as: 'sensor_data',
        });
      };




//models/sensordata.js


sensor_data.associate = function(models) {
    sensor_data.belongsTo(models.device, {
      foreignKey: 'sensor_device_id',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    });
  };




//models/actuatoractivity.js


    actuator_activity.associate = function(models) {
        actuator_activity.belongsTo(models.device, {
          foreignKey: 'actuator_device_id',
          onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        });
        actuator_activity.belongsTo(models.device, {
          foreignKey: 'sensor_device_id',
          onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        });
      };
```

running this query

```
device.findAll({include:[{model: sensor_data, as: 'sensor_data'}, {model: actuator_activity, as: 'actuator_activities'}]})
```

returns this:

```
{
            "id": 2,
            "name": "TEST DEVICE 2",
            "role": "SENSOR",
            "type": "SOIL MOISTURE",
            "io_pin": 5,
            "added_timestamp": "2019-05-01T12:18:08.317Z",
            "client_added_timestamp": "2019-04-23T20:44:29.597Z",
            "min_value": 0,
            "max_value": 1000,
            "sensor_data": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "sensor_device_id": 2,
                    "created_timestamp": "2019-04-23T20:44:29.597Z",
                    "sensor_value": 300
                }
            ],
            "actuator_activities": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "created_timestamp": "2019-04-23T20:44:29.597Z",
                    "name": "Motor turned on",
                    "actuator_device_id": 1,
                    "sensor_device_id": 2
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "TEST DEVICE 1",
            "role": "ACTUATOR",
            "type": "MOTOR",
            "io_pin": 7,
            "added_timestamp": "2019-05-01T12:17:14.026Z",
            "client_added_timestamp": "2019-04-23T20:44:29.597Z",
            "min_value": 0,
            "max_value": 1,
            "sensor_data": [],
            "actuator_activities": []
        }
```

but what I want to get is this:

```
{
            "id": 2,
            "name": "TEST DEVICE 2",
            "role": "SENSOR",
            "type": "SOIL MOISTURE",
            "io_pin": 5,
            "added_timestamp": "2019-05-01T12:18:08.317Z",
            "client_added_timestamp": "2019-04-23T20:44:29.597Z",
            "min_value": 0,
            "max_value": 1000,
            "sensor_data": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "sensor_device_id": 2,
                    "created_timestamp": "2019-04-23T20:44:29.597Z",
                    "sensor_value": 300
                }
            ],

        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "TEST DEVICE 1",
            "role": "ACTUATOR",
            "type": "MOTOR",
            "io_pin": 7,
            "added_timestamp": "2019-05-01T12:17:14.026Z",
            "client_added_timestamp": "2019-04-23T20:44:29.597Z",
            "min_value": 0,
            "max_value": 1,
            "actuator_activities": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "created_timestamp": "2019-04-23T20:44:29.597Z",
                    "name": "Motor turned on",
                    "actuator_device_id": 1,
                    "sensor_device_id": 2
                }
            ]
        }
```

The idea here is to match the `id` with the nested `actuator_device_id` and `sensor_device_id`

if I remove the associations with `actuator_activity` and `devices` with foreign key `sensor_device_id` It works as I expect but I need to keep this because I need the cascading option for `actuator_activity` for both the columns.

Is there a way, for example, When querying I could specify to ignore/exclude this specific foreign key?

If not how can I achieve my goals here?

Help would be very much appreciated, Thank you for reading the long post.